# How can I ban a Maven dependency where the version contains a certain part?

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I'm tryin to use [Maven Enforcer's banned dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) where I want to ban that there are `compile` and `runtime` dependencies to any artifact that contains `-redhat-`. The background of this: The JEE API and other stuff already exists in the JBoss AS and should never be included in the EAR.

This is what I'm trying, but it doesn't work:

> ```
>       <execution>
>         <id>banned-dependencies</id>
>         <goals>
>           <goal>enforce</goal>
>         </goals>
>         <configuration>
>           <rules>
>             <bannedDependencies>
>               <searchTransitive>false</searchTransitive>
>               <excludes>
>                 <exclude>*:*:*-redhat-*:*:compile</exclude>
>                 <exclude>*:*:*-redhat-*:*:runtime</exclude>
>               </excludes>
>             </bannedDependencies>
>           </rules>
>           <fail>true</fail>
>         </configuration>
>       </execution>
> ```

Comment: Based on the docs i would assume your excludes are not correct. Cause the docs define the format like this: `org.apache.maven:*:*:jar:test` `groupId:artifactId:version:packaging:scope` In your case you seemed to checking only the version which contains `*-redhat-*` which i assume which is not what you intended to do? BTW: Where did you found `searchTransitive`? Do you get an error message?

Comment: No, I **do** want to exclude just anything with a version that contains `-redhat-` (and the mentioned scopes). As for `searchTransitive`, I'm not sure, perhaps it was copy&paste from the web. But it exists in the class: http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/apidocs/org/apache/maven/plugins/enforcer/AbstractBanDependencies.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered this wont work the way you are wanting. (I presume you are finding that the enforcer plugin is matching all dependencies listed in your pom?)

The problem is that Maven expects the `version` given to either be a single `*` or to conform to maven's [Version Spec](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html). (i.e. `1.0`, `[1.0,)` etc)  It can't handle the multiple wildcards that you are using.

Unfortunately I don't really have a solution for you. You could potentially 
[Write Your Own Rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) and extend the `BannedDependencies` rule and have it work the way you would like.

#### *What follows is a dive into the code that is causing your issue*

In the `BannedDependencies` class there is the following check for the version given in the `exclude` string:

```java
if (pattern[2].equals("*") || artifact.getVersion().equals(pattern[2]) ) {
    result = true;
} else {
    try {
        result = AbstractVersionEnforcer.containsVersion(
                VersionRange.createFromVersionSpec(pattern[2]),
                new DefaultArtifactVersion(artifact.getBaseVersion()));
    } catch ( InvalidVersionSpecificationException e ) {
        throw new EnforcerRuleException("Invalid Version Range: ", e);
    }
}
```

The specific problem for you is

```
AbstractVersionEnforcer.containsVersion(
       VersionRange.createFromVersionSpec(pattern[2]),
       new DefaultArtifactVersion(artifact.getBaseVersion()))
```

You can see that it is expecting a `VersionRange` due to `VersionRange.createFromVersionSpec()`. The code for that can be seen here:
[VersionRange source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven/maven-artifact/2.0.6/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/VersionRange.java)

Comment: Hmm... did I misunderstand the documentation? `Wildcards may be used to replace an entire or just parts of a section`

Comment: @eerriicc, not sure what to say. I appreciate this isn't the answer you were hoping for, but from the code it certainly seems to me you can only use either a single `*` or a `VersionSpec`, but not a combination of the two. I tested your scenario and had the same problem. You could try something along the lines of `[1.0,)` which basically means all versions starting with 1.0 and above. So if you used the starting version of your redhat dependencies then all versions should be matched.